# How can I align entries in the column?

Tags: xy-pic

I have drawn the following picture in xypic[image]

and I would like to align in the right column the Hom term in the first row as well as direct product guys in the 2nd and 3rd rows exactly together. How can I do this? Because right now the diagram is looking odd. For those interested, here is my code:

```
\[\begin{xy} \xymatrix@C=5em@R=4em{  \Hom(X,\spec A) \ar[r]^\alpha \ar[d] &  \operatorname{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)) \ar[d] \
\prod_i \Hom(U_i,A) \ar[r]^-{\beta_i} \ar@<-0.5ex>[d] \ar@<0.5ex>[d] &\prod_i \operatorname{Hom}\Big(A,\Gamma(U_i,\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}) \Big)  \ar@<-0.5ex>[d] \ar@<0.5ex>[d] \
\prod_{i,j} \Hom(U_i \cap U_j,A) \ar[r]^-{\beta_{i,j}} & \prod_{i,j}  \operatorname{Hom}\Big(A,\Gamma(U_i \cap U_j,\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i\cap U_j}) \Big)   }\end{xy}\]
```

Comment: I think that it is not possible on xy. Do you know tikz-cd?

Comment: Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E2mjn.png) for the RHS?

Comment: @Werner Perhaps but is it possible for them to be perfectly alinged?

Comment: @Sigur I am not using it now, but if you show me the code I am prepared to change from xypic to tikz-cd.

Comment: @BenjaLim: According to your post, you want the `Hom` operator name to be aligned horizontally across the rows. Am I right? That's exactly what I have in my picture. Sure, you want it for the LHS as well, correct? Perhaps use a graphic interface and mock up the *exact* output you're after as well.

Comment: @Werner I actually want the Hom term in the top right entry to be aligned with the ***direct product*** guy in the second row, and also aligned in with the ***direct product*** guy in the third row.

Comment: @BenjaLim: Please provide a clear image of what you're after. Not everyone knows what "direct product" means... Open up a copy of the image (say, a screen grab) and move the elements around in a graphic editor. Draw arrows and mark the drawing if need be. It will make things *much* more clear.

Comment: @BenjaLim The way you want to typeset the diagram looks odd to me and the current version seems pretty good (I'd avoid `\Big`, maybe `\big` or nothing at all).

Answer (score 1):

This is a first cut.  I'm sure something can be done better with the arrows than just stretching them (as I did).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\spec{\mathrm{Spec}}
\def\Hom{\mystrut\mathrm{Hom}}
\def\bigdownarrow{\stretchto{\downarrow}{6ex}}
\def\bigrightarrow{\protect\hstretch{5}{\rightarrow}}
\def\nobigdownarrow{\protect\phantom{\bigdownarrow}}
\newcommand\rarrow[1]{\mystrut\smash{\stackon{$\bigrightarrow$}{$#1$}}}
\def\hgapa{\hspace{5ex}}
\def\hgapb{\hspace{4.5ex}}
\def\mystrut{\protect\vphantom{\Big(}}
\begin{document}
\[
\Shortstack[r]{{} {$\nobigdownarrow$} {$\prod_{i,j}\mystrut$}
 {$\nobigdownarrow$} {$\prod_{i,j}\mystrut$}}
\Shortstack[l]{{$\Hom(X, \spec A)$} {$\hgapa\bigdownarrow$} {$\Hom(U_i, A)$}
  {$\hgapb\bigdownarrow\bigdownarrow$} {$\Hom(U_i \cap U_j,A)$}}
\Shortstack[c]{{$\rarrow{\alpha}$} {$\nobigdownarrow$} {$\rarrow{\beta_i}$}
  {$\nobigdownarrow$} {$\rarrow{\beta_{i,j}}$}}
\Shortstack[r]{{} {$\nobigdownarrow$} {$\prod_{i,j}\mystrut$}
 {$\nobigdownarrow$} {$\prod_{i,j}\mystrut$}}
\Shortstack[l]{{$\Hom(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$} {$\hgapa\bigdownarrow$}
  {$\Hom\Big(A,\Gamma(U_i,\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}) \Big)$}
  {$\hgapb\bigdownarrow\bigdownarrow$} 
  {$\Hom\Big(A,\Gamma(U_i \cap U_j,\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i\cap U_j}) \Big)  $}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]